# relative path in python few folders up

Tags: python

I have following folder structure on Win7 machine:

```
C:\dev\bin\toplevel\python
```

I am running a script, say **p1.py** in this folder.
I need to create folder termed **Myscript** under

```
C:\dev\matlab\scripts
```

I need to use path relative to my current folder `\python`.
I tried using:

```
LibPathTst= '.\\dev\matlab\\scripts'
  os.makedirs(LibPathTst)
```

but this creates:

```
C:\dev\bin\toplevel\python\dev\matlab\scripts
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
../../../matlab/scripts
```

Should be what you are looking for. Since you are using python, `os.path.relpath` (with the two paths as arts) gives you this result.

In a directory, there are two "special" nodes: "." and "..", pointing to the current directory and the parent directory, respectively.

Comment: You should also include that `../` refers to the parent directory